# How to automatically generate variables and its assaignment?

Tags: python, automation

I wonder if there is a way to generate new variables and its assaignment based on a particular global variable.

I have the following code which belongs to a larger code function. In this particular case:

```
VNF_TYPES = 2 

# Sum up vnf event per type in transitioned state
  total_vnf = [0]*VNF_TYPES 
  for event in states[key][0]:
    total_vnf[0] += event[0]
    total_vnf[1] += event[1]
```

If I change the value of:

```
VNF_TYPES = 4
```

Is there a way to automatically generate new variables and its assaignments in such a way that it results in:

```
# Sum up vnf event per type in transitioned state
  total_vnf = [0]*VNF_TYPES 
  for event in states[key][0]:
    total_vnf[0] += event[0]
    total_vnf[1] += event[1]
    total_vnf[2] += event[2] # automatically generated
    total_vnf[3] += event[3] # automatically generated
```

Comment: Why don't you just iterate over all the indices?

Comment: The size of total_vnf changes when it does VNF_TYPE

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: No it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.... would it work ? I don't have your entire code so not sure what will end up with:

```
VNF_TYPE = 4
#Sum up vnf event per type in transitioned state
# total_vnf = [0]*VNF_TYPES 
for event in states[key][0]:
    for i in range(VNF_TYPE):
        total_vnf[i] += event[i]
```

give us a minimal reproducible example to work with

Comment: Is bit difficult for me to give you a minimal reproducible example since the code lines that I wrote on the post belong to a function that at the same time it feeds from other functions. Nevertheless, your suggestion has helped me to achieve what I was trying, so I give it as an answer. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```py
  total_vnf = [0]*VNF_TYPES 
  for event in states[key][0]:
      for pos in range(VNF_TYPES):
        total_vnf[pos] += event[pos]
```